# Filtrar objetos mediante otro objeto cuando los objetos no son idénticos

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo un lista de casas con las características enumeradas en `tagsProperty`, necesito encontrar las casas que cumplan con los requerimientos del `contacto` enlistados en la propiedad con el mismo nombre (`tagsProperty`). Solo funciona si contacto tiene un requerimiento.

```js
let filtProperty = [];
let casas = [
  {
    colonia: "Cordilleras",
    tagsProperty: ["frente a parque", "recamara en pb", "fraccionamiento privado", "nueva"]
  },
  {
    colonia: "Panoramico",
    tagsProperty: ["frente a parque", "recamara en pb"]
  },
  {
    colonia: "Mirador",
    tagsProperty: ["frente a parque", "fraccionamiento privado", "una Planta", "nueva"]
  }];

let contacto = {
  name: "Juan",
  tagsProperty: ["una Planta", "nueva"]
}

filtProperty = casas.filter(item => JSON.stringify(item.tagsProperty).includes(contacto.tagsProperty));

console.log(filtProperty)
```

Comment: ¿ Las casas tienen que cumplir con todos los requerimientros al mismo tiempo o basta con que cumpla uno solo para que pueda ser considerada?

Comment: el tema es que includes() evalua las propiedades de a una, prueba a poner: let contacto = {name: "Juan",
        tagsProperty: ["frente a parque", "nueva" ]} y luego filtProperty = casas.filter((item,) => (item.tagsProperty).includes(contacto.tagsProperty[0])); y veras como te trae todas las que tengan frente a parque, de igual manera si pones como indice [1] te traera un array con las que tienen la propiedad "nueva". Por lo tanto deberia buscar la manera de hacer una evaluacion de cada propiedad por separado y juntarlas en un nuevo array

Comment: Prueba a utilizar [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que está bien usar `.filter`, pero dentro del filter se podría usar `.some` o `.every` para ver si se quieren cumplir alguna o todas las condiciones respectivamente.

```js
let casas = [{"colonia":"Cordilleras","tagsProperty":["frente a parque","recamara en pb","fraccionamiento privado","nueva"]},{"colonia":"Panoramico","tagsProperty":["frente a parque","recamara en pb"]},{"colonia":"Mirador","tagsProperty":["frente a parque","fraccionamiento privado","una Planta","nueva"]}];

let contacto = {name: "Juan",tagsProperty: ["una Planta", "nueva"]}

const cumpleTodas = casas.filter(e => contacto.tagsProperty.every(c => e.tagsProperty.includes(c)));

const cumpleAlguna = casas.filter(e => contacto.tagsProperty.some(c => e.tagsProperty.includes(c)));


console.log("cumple todas las condiciones: ",cumpleTodas);
console.log("cumple alguna de las condiciones: ",cumpleAlguna);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solución

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
let filtProperty = [];
let casas = [
  {
    colonia: "Cordilleras",
    tagsProperty: ["frente a parque", "recamara en pb", "fraccionamiento privado", "nueva"]
  },
  {
    colonia: "Panoramico",
    tagsProperty: ["frente a parque", "recamara en pb"]
  },
  {
    colonia: "Mirador",
    tagsProperty: ["frente a parque", "fraccionamiento privado", "una Planta", "nueva"]
  },
  {
    colonia: "Casa que coincide",
    tagsProperty: ["una Planta", "nueva"]
  },
];

let contacto = {
  name: "Juan",
  tagsProperty: ["una Planta", "nueva"]
}

filtProperty = casas.filter(casa =>
   contacto.tagsProperty.every(tag => 
      casa.tagsProperty.includes(tag))
);

console.log(filtProperty)
```

### Explicación

> necesito encontrar las casas que cumplan con los requerimientos del contacto enlistados en la propiedad con el mismo nombre (tagsProperty).

Según el requerimiento, encontrar las casas que tengan los tags que tiene el contacto, podemos usar el método [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) para chequear que el cada tag del contacto exista en los tags de la casa.

Lo anterior se encuentra en esta parte del código:

```javascript
filtProperty = casas.filter(casa =>
  contacto.tagsProperty.every(tag => // Usamos "every" para preguntar por cada tag del contacto (Devuelve true si todos cumplen con la condición
      casa.tagsProperty.includes(tag)) // La condición que usamos es que "casa.tagsProperty" uncluya el tag del contacto
);
```